# How to pivot a row into a multi-variate table?

Tags: r, tidyverse, pivot-table

I've never been good at pivot tables so I'm not sure if the terminology I'm using is even very accurate, but here goes:

Some other users on StackOverflow have helped me with some code that calculates a large number of risk ratios for a number of items (in this case different foods). The code prints out the ratios along with the foods they correspond to in a long row like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  thurs_brkf_banana thurs_brkf_orange thurs_lun_turkey thurs_lun_cheese thurs_din_spaghetti thurs_din_bread
              <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>           <dbl>
1               1.2               3.7              8.4              2.5                 4.5             1.7
```

As you can see, this format isn't  helpful for further data analysis because the day (thurs), the meal (brkf, lun, din), and the type of food are all in the same variable. I would prefer to have them separated out and have the risk ratio as it's own column. Something that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  day   meal  food         rr
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 thurs brkf  banana      1.2
2 thurs brkf  orange      3.7
3 thurs lun   turkey      8.4
4 thurs lun   cheese      2.5
5 thurs din   spaghetti   4.5
6 thurs din   bread       1.7
```

Any help coding this would be helpful! I just hand typed these different datasets in excel but I have no idea how to switch from one to the other in R.

Answer (score 3):

Append the `rr` at the end of the column name and use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_c(.x, "_rr")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
   names_to = c("day", "meal", "food", ".value"), names_sep = "_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  day   meal  food         rr
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 thurs brkf  banana      1.2
2 thurs brkf  orange      3.7
3 thurs lun   turkey      8.4
4 thurs lun   cheese      2.5
5 thurs din   spaghetti   4.5
6 thurs din   bread       1.7
```

---

Or another option is to do the standard `pivot_longer` and separate the names column

```
pivot_longer(df1, cols = everything(), values_to = 'rr') %>%
  separate_wider_delim(name, delim = "_",
    names = c("day", "meal", "food"))
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  day   meal  food         rr
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 thurs brkf  banana      1.2
2 thurs brkf  orange      3.7
3 thurs lun   turkey      8.4
4 thurs lun   cheese      2.5
5 thurs din   spaghetti   4.5
6 thurs din   bread       1.7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(thurs_brkf_banana = 1.2, thurs_brkf_orange = 3.7, 
    thurs_lun_turkey = 8.4, thurs_lun_cheese = 2.5, thurs_din_spaghetti = 4.5, 
    thurs_din_bread = 1.7), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: sorry @akrun I should have worded that differently. It did solve the problem! Thanks a lot!